# git rebase onto shows old commits that have already been merged

Tags: github, rebase

Essentially, I followed these steps: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/How-to-Rebase-a-Pull-Request

The only difference is that I used `get rebase onto master` to sync master into my feature branch. This is my workflow:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout <my branch>
git rebase onto master
git push -f origin <my branch>
```

However, when I now go into github to do a pull request, it is showing old commits that have already been merged.

Comment: Why not just merging 'master' branch in 'my-branch', then create a Pull request?   As you are rebasing so, commit hashes are changed.

Comment: @sajib you've missed the whole point of rebase. With merge you get an extra commit. See the article I referenced